# How to post to Facebook feed big picture?

Tags: php, facebook, api, image

I wrote very small and easy function to post messages on facebook fanpage feed. Everything is fine. Message is added correcly to feed but I want post picture too. When I post url image in parameter "picture", this image is small on the wall.

```
$params = array('access_token'=>'mycode', 'message'=>'msg', 'source'=>'url image');
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/twojachmuracom/feed";
```

If you write message on Facebook and you added picture you have big image in the post. Any sugestions how can I post big picture with API?

Comment: Your question would be stronger if you referenced your findings from reading and following the official Facebook documentation about this. What do the official docs have to say about this?

Answer (score 0):

with your code you are sharing a simple link, you should use another API method to upload a photo, take a look these tutorials, hope it helps!

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/uploadphoto/
- https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/